# Getting methods from more classes in php

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance

I have a base class `List` is almost a pure array.
I have an ordered list `OrderedList` when all items got a number about its order
I have a checkbox list `CheckboxList` when a check box is before all items (the lists stores a boolean value).

Now I want to have an ordered checkbox list class. So it should inherits 2 classes. How to workaround this?

Comment: Some code sample (precisely concise [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) is essential

Comment: Past your code. Anyway, about multiple inheritance, you could to read about Traits. A new feature on php (version 5.4.0). http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 2):

First if all, you should favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). It might be that your "can I inherit from multiple classes" is a sign if design flaw.

Anyway, if you need an "ordered checkbox list class" then the structure should be:

```
class OrderedList extends List{}

class CheckboxList extends OrderedList{}
```

Additionally, i would suggest to avoid using traits in this case , because *Traits* in php are actually Interpretator aided Copy'n'Paste. There is no clear benefit for this.

Btw, there is another approach you might look at: while CheckboxList extends List, you might have some other object responsible for ordering it. Hell , if you implement [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) for the `List` class, you might be able use just the built in `sort()`/`usort()` function (or `ksory()`/`uksort()` depending on how you store the fields) .. thought i have not tried it actually.

Answer (score 1):

PHP of course does not support multiple inheritance. If you're ready for the bleeding edge, you can use traits in PHP 5.4. Otherwise, try Googling "PHP mixins" to find a mixin implementation.